# I'm getting a TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, flash, session
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from models import connect_db, db, User, Feedback
from forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, FeedbackForm
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError


@app.route("/users/<username>/feedback/add", methods=["GET"])
definitely add_feedback(username):
    """Add feedback for specific user"""
    if "username" not in session or username != session["username"]:
        flash("Please login to leave feedback!")
        return redirect(f"/users/{username}/feedback/add")

    form = FeedbackForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = form.title.data
        content = form.content.data

        new_feedback = Feedback(title=title, content=content, username=username)

        db.session.add(new_feedback)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("/feedback/add.html", form=form)
```

Please help! I keep getting
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. This is a get route, and should show the user a feedback form.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized why I was getting this error. The indentation is wrong on the return render_template statement. I also changed the redirect url to "/login".